# Can I force empathy to open links in default browser?

Tags: empathy, default-browser

Recently empathy has switched it's behavior for open links.

At some point it was that links pasted in the IM window where open with whatever program was associated to the mime type of the link's content type, so, for example if the link was pointing to a image it was open in eog, if the link was a webpage it was open in gedit (my default setting).

Now it opens everything in chrome even though it's not my default browser, I've checked everywhere and chrome is not set as default.

I'm thinking that it's a bug but wanted to ask before going to launchpad. It's happening the same to you?

Is there a way to force empathy to open everything in firefox as a workaround?

Comment: This seems similar to [Bug #576734 - Empathy does not honor default browser when clicking URLs in chat](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/576734)

Comment: What's the output for "file /etc/alternatives/x-www-browser"?

Comment: I've already switched to Chrome as my default browser so I can't really comply :(. Nice to know the bug was reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the same issue on my Ubuntu installation by reading through @fluteflute's comment above in Bug #576734 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/576734).

Specifically this comment in the thread:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/576734/comments/4

hope it helps.

Comment: here, have a vote :)

Answer (score 3):

If you go to System > Preferences > Preferred Applications (or run "gnome-default-applications-properties" on the command line), you can select which web browser GNOME will regard as your default browser, which Empathy will respect.

Comment: Note: This is the same as jairo's answer, I just wanted to provide the information in a more accessible way.